# jackson empty query param behavior

Tags: java, rest, jackson, glassfish

I am working in a REST service using javax.ws.rs, running under Glassfish, and I have some strange behavior differences on different servers, regarding the interpretation of empty query params.
*Note, actual names of services and implementation details deemed unimportant have had their names changed or been omitted, to protect the innocent.*

Some (most) servers treat a request

> http://localhost/serviceRoot/orders?status=

(i.e. a query param named status is provided, but with no value after the = sign) as equivalent to

> http://localhost/serviceRoot/orders

essentially letting that query param be null, but some treat it as though that query param had the value of "" (empty-string).

This is a problem in my case, because:

```
/* In a Resource class, I have this method defined: */
@GET
@Path("/orders")
public Response getOrders(@QueryParam("status") OrderStatus orderStatus) throws Exception {
    /* code to pull orders, optionally by status, and return them in a Response */
}

/* ... and elsewhere, our enum */    
public enum OrderStatus {
    RECEIVED, ACKNOWLEDGED, CANCELLED
}
```

and when someone sends the first request above to a server which treats it as an empty string, I get an error in the form:

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.fqcn.OrderStatus."
```

(because "" is not a valid value in the enum which it tries to automatically construct) whereas it would successfully retrieve a list of orders, if the request hit a different server.

In order to debug, though I was not able to make it produce a stack trace under normal execution, I was able to write an ExceptionMapper, and output the stack trace of that, explicitly, so I came up with this:

```
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.QueryParamInjectableProvider$QueryParamInjectable.getValue(QueryParamInjectableProvider.java:74),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349),
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339),
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416),
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537),
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708),
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161),
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331),
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231),
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317),
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195),
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860),
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757),
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056),
com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229),
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137),
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104),
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90),
com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79),
com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54),
com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59),
com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71),
com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532),
com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513),
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

My problem is: I do not know where this query-param interpreting behavior resides (what config file, or class/jar file), and I do not have control over the clients requesting this. Furthermore, the "big red button" approach of taking down the offending servers and standing up new clones from a "known good" instance is time-expensive and has to be done very carefully.

The question I would like answered is: Where, if anywhere within Glassfish or Jackson (or another layer of the service stack?), is this empty-query-param interpreting behavior configured, and how do I change it?

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Unfortunately, the exception is caught and automatically transformed into a JSON error response and does not produce a stack trace. I'll see what I can do to reproduce it locally in debug mode, and see if I can determine where the exception occurs.

Comment: I managed to produce a stack by using an ExceptionMapper to capture the exception produced, and have added that to the question.

Comment: It has been explained to me that an older version of jackson (say, 2.1.x) has has the behavior where the two scenarios are treated as a null value, and newer versions (>=2.2) treat the two scenarios as distinct, the one passing null and the other passing an empty string as the value. Not sure which version exactly contains the change, but that's where our problem lies.

Given that later versions treat the scenarios as distinct, we'll have to ensure the requestors of the service are specific about which query params they pass.